# How to display "Loading..." with having 3 dots animating using C++?

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

You may have seen in many places **"Loading...**" where the 3 dots(or more), viz. "...", first appear one by one, then after displaying all the dots, they disapperar and once again appear one by one (so, total 2 times).

To elaborate:-

Stage 1:

> Loading.

Stage 2:

> Loading..

Stage 3:

> Loading...
>
> Then, it repeats second time! and then terminate!

So, for this I prepared a C++ program and its source code is:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <time.h>
#include<dos.h>
int main()
{
    cout << "Loading";
    cout.flush();
    for (;;) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            cout << ".";
            cout.flush();
            sleep(1);
        }
        cout << "\b\b\b   \b\b\b";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This program is not terminating. It doesn't stops! How can I edit this to make this terminate?

Please post codes supported by **Turbo C++ Compiler**, as I am not too much aware of the ANSI C++!! :P

Gguys, please help me out? :)

Thanks, in advance! :)

Comment: You would need to tell where there are incompatibilites with Turbo C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go for the following solution using "carriage return":

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
   cout << "\rLoading   \rLoading";
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      cout << ".";
      sleep(300);
   }
}
```

This overwrites the current line (with all dots) and repostions cursor at the end of "Loading".

BTW, the sleep value here is in milliseconds. You may have to change that if yours is in seconds.

Also, in your program you have nested loops both with running `i` - I doubt that this will work as intended...

Comment: What do you want to change?

Comment: the program is not stopping! It is continuously running, how can I stop this? Can u plz suggest me? :)

Comment: What have you changed? If using the `for(;;)` like you wrote above that's an endless loop indeed. Change it back to something with limits.

Answer (score 3):

Why not delete those points using a backspace?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Loading";
    cout.flush();
    for (;;) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            cout << ".";
            cout.flush();
            sleep(1);
        }
        cout << "\b\b\b   \b\b\b";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By the way, the logic here is "move the cursor back three spaces", then "overwrite the dots with blank spaces", then "move the cursor back three spaces"

Comment: Oh and I do apologize for the `using namespace std;` but I wanted to type as fast as possible :P

Comment: Can you please provide code that is compatible with Turbo compilers?

Comment: @SubhadeepDey Well, is this not?

Comment: @SubhadeepDey (a. k. a. Can **you** please come back to the XXIth century and start using G++ instead of TC++?)

Comment: @H2CO3, no I can't! I have Code Blocks with MinGW Compiler, but I prefer TC++ 3.0 more!

Comment: @H2CO3, pooops, your code has an error!!!

It says "Sleep was not declared in this scope"

Comment: @SubhadeepDey I can't help but keep telling you to switch off from TC++. It's dead. If you use it, you're dead too. If it doesn't have `sleep()` in `<ctime>`, then your toolchain isn't worth a cent.

Comment: @H2CO3, yeah, I agree because I can't do anything as my school uses it! So, I have to use it! (But after my high-school, I will switch to another modern compiler)

Comment: @H2CO3, I tested your code in Code Blocks 12.11. It said "Sleep was not declared in this scope". And, I edited your code compatible with TC++, but it runs without terminating.... It's ENDLESS.

How can I stop it?

Comment: @SubhadeepDey `<ctrl> + <Z>`